# C++ Visual Studio 2008, delete() operation crashes program

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2008, delete-operator

Since some days, I have been facing a problem in Visual Studio 2008, related to my C++ software.
If I set Visual Studio settings to "Release Win32" mode, it works fine.

But if I set it to "Debug Win32", it has crash problems when using delete. Compiling is alright, but, when running, the software crashes on 1st "delete" it meets.

Consider this snaphsot:

[image]

As you can see, when software arrives to "delete temp;" command execution, it crashes showing the message:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Program...
>   Expression _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockHouse)

What is the problem?
How to solve it?

Why in "Release" mode it doesn't have any errors?

Thanx

Comment: Can you post the code rather than a screen shot.

Comment: In release the compiler doesn't do assertions by default. This is why it compiles without error

Comment: `temp` is `NULL`. Doing anything with `NULL` is bad, and presumable visual studio has some kind off assert in debug mode, which it disables in release mode. Then you are unlucky enough that it doesn't crash, and appears to work.

Comment: I guess your program has a bug, which doesnt appear in Release mode.
One thing to note here which is the cause of these bugs is most likely that in debug mode all variables are initialized to dump, while in release mode they are initialized to 0, this can cause some bugs when allocating the memory.

Comment: @v01d: *runs* without error ... compile-time vs. run-time :) ... besides it's clearly not running without errors, just hiding them, I presume.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED I said that the compiler doesn't do assertions in release mode, nothing about will it run or not.

Comment: @v01d: I must have miread this then: "This is why it *compiles* without error" ;) (emphasis mine)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. Nothing else. You're also trying to use a null pointer to call a function. What happens when you try to call a method of nothing? Well, it can't be anything good.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it, remember it is usually preferable to allocate something on the stack than with `new`. It's shorter, and you don't have to clean up. If you really need `new`, you should look into smart pointers, as they manage the memory for you.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: in modern C++, the rule of thumb is: _"if you are calling `new`, you're probably doing something wrong"_. As already written, try to allocate on the stack or at least use smart pointers and stuff like `make_unique`, `make_shared`, etc.

Comment: @chris: Your correct sentence can be more complete like this: you should only `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]` what you `new[]` **using the same flavor of the CRT**. In fact, e.g. new'ing something in a DLL built with VCx and deleting the returned pointer in an .EXE built with VCy can crash.

Comment: @Mr_C64, a good point, although a bit beyond the scope of the problem here.

Answer (score 3):

You have temp = NULL and on the next line you call a method on it? And then you try do delete it?

---

In addition to that assertions aren't "errors". Assertions are there in debug mode to declare that you are asserting a certain condition (these often are also included throughout libraries such as the MFC) and if your assertion fails it calls code to inform you about it and give you the chance to break into the debugger in order to debug the issue.

Comment: `delete NULL` is perfectly fine. It is a no-op. Invoking a member function on a NULL object of course invokes UB -- which I think is the problem.

Comment: @izomorphius it's not that. If I removed it, it simply crashes on the next delete... fstream uscita; uscita.open("valori.txt", ios::out); uscita.close(); delete uscita; >>>it crashes

Comment: @DavidChicco.it: You cannot `delete` an automatic object. That's UB again. You can only (safely) call delete on (valid) pointers.

Comment: I never said it is error to delete NULL. But do these lines make sense to you? Define something to be NULL and delete it on the next line? Come on it is obvious nonsense

Comment: @DavideChicco.it, I think you're just trying to clean up. You don't have to worry about that unless you're allocating memory to raw pointers with `new` or `new[]`. Other things, like an `fstream` object,  will be destructed when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger does an "assertion". This is an additional check for correctness of the code like eg: "assert that the pointer is not null.". It's good that it is doing so, because it helps finding errors. I agree to anybody who claims that the message emitted by the debugger does not help finding the source for the error.